# Group BY DESC being ignored after join - Mysql 5

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, foreign-key

### The problem I wish to solve

I am trying to select the trucks that are on duty. I tried using sub queries. However, I heard that it has bad performance. I also tried adding a `is_onduty` flag to the `truck` table, but I feel that it could cause potential issues should the application crash.

> tl;dr:
> I wish to join 2 tables by a foreign key and select
> the distinct records of the foreign key

### fiddle

```
select version();
```

| version() |
| --- |
| 5.7.39 |

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `truck` (
  `truck_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,    # license plate
  `is_online` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`truck_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```
INSERT INTO truck(truck_id) VALUES 
  ("ABC123"),
  ("DEF123"),
  ("ADF134");
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM truck
```

| truck_id | is_online | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 0 | *null* |
| ADF134 | 0 | *null* |
| DEF123 | 0 | *null* |

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consignment` (
  `consignment_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shipment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `transporter` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `truck_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`consignment_id`),
  KEY `consignment_truck_id_index` (`truck_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```
INSERT INTO consignment(shipment, transporter, truck_id) VALUES 
  ("shipment1", "transporter1", "ABC123"), 
  ("shipment2", "transporter2", "ABC123"), 
  ("shipment3", "transporter3", "DEF123"),
  ("shipment4", "transporter4", "DEF123"),
  ("shipment5", "transporter5", "DEF123"),
  ("shipment6", "transporter6", "DEF123");
```

> ```
> Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM consignment
```

| consignment_id | shipment | transporter | truck_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | shipment1 | transporter1 | ABC123 |
| 31 | shipment2 | transporter2 | ABC123 |
| 32 | shipment3 | transporter3 | DEF123 |
| 33 | shipment4 | transporter4 | DEF123 |
| 34 | shipment5 | transporter5 | DEF123 |
| 35 | shipment6 | transporter6 | DEF123 |

```
SELECT c.*, t.*
FROM consignment as c
JOIN truck as t
ON c.`truck_id` = t.truck_id
GROUP BY c.truck_id DESC;
```

#### Expected

| consignment_id | shipment | transporter | truck_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | shipment2 | transporter2 | ABC123 |
| 35 | shipment6 | transporter6 | DEF123 |

#### Received in phpmyadmin

| consignment_id | shipment | transporter | truck_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | shipment1 | transporter1 | ABC123 |
| 32 | shipment3 | transporter3 | DEF123 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9yNb_3Lq)

Comment: Please correct your data example and expected result. [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). *Note*, sql_mode only_full_group_by should be enabled

Comment: ASC/DESC in GROUP BY cannot specify what value from all possible in a group will be taken for non-aggregated and non-grouped output column. You must create an expression which will select the value from needed row in the group. You need to add a subquery which will allow to do this.

Comment: @ErgestBasha tks, I have updated my description. However, `only_full_group` seemed to caused some error

Comment: @Akina Tks, I tried out sub query and it works! However, I am a bit reluctant to use it in production as I heard that it is bad for performance

Comment: @Polygorial I did not encounter any issue. The reason why I had issues previously was because I came up with a complicated sub query that did not rely on the index: `consignment_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried out sub query and it works! However, I am a bit reluctant to
> use it in production as I heard that it is bad for performance

In your case you have to use a subquery to get latest consignment_id , with the correct indexes which it seems you have it it will not be performance bad.

```
SELECT c.*, t.*
FROM consignment as c
JOIN  truck as t ON c.`truck_id` = t.truck_id
inner join (select max(consignment_id) as consignment_id,
                   truck_id
            from consignment
            group by truck_id 
           ) as max_id on max_id.consignment_id=c.consignment_id   ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/OVMCrrxM

> However, only_full_group_by seemed to caused some error

[ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

From the 8.0.13 Changelog:

> The deprecated ASC or DESC qualifiers for GROUP BY clauses have been
> removed. Queries that previously relied on GROUP BY sorting may
> produce results that differ from previous MySQL versions. To produce a
> given sort order, provide an ORDER BY clause.
>
> Queries and stored
> program definitions from MySQL 8.0.12 or lower that use ASC or DESC
> qualifiers for GROUP BY clauses should be amended. Otherwise,
> upgrading to MySQL 8.0.13 or higher may fail, as may replicating to
> MySQL 8.0.13 or higher slave servers.

In 5.7.23, the above was "deprecated and will be removed in a future MySQL version".

Also, an `ORDER BY` on a 'derived table' may be useful if there is also a `LIMIT`.  But in no case is the ordering retained for the parent `SELECT`.